# Java: Text on button disappearing upon a mouseEvent changing its color

Tags: java, button, text, colors

So, what I'm trying to do is a button with text on it.

When the user hovers on the button, the text color changes from a base color (bcolornorm) to the color set for hovering (bcolorhover). Upon clicking it changes from bcolorhover to bcolorclic.

However, what is happening is that upon hovering, the text simply disappears (I assume the color is set to null) and doesn't reappear no matter what I do.

Here's the code :

Window class: http://pastebin.com/Pcp0Ztks
Button class: http://pastebin.com/438Jf33m

How it works:

There is a variable named bcolor that is changed based on the mouseEvents.

Upon initializing it takes the value of bcolornorm, then takes the value of bcolornorm, bcolorhover or bcolorclic depending on the mouseEvents.

The color is then set using g2d.setColor(bcolor).

I've tried removing the "this" in the variables but it doesn't work. I honestly can't think of why bcolor is set to null and doesn't take the value of the other variables.

Anybody has a solution? Thanks :)

Comment: Well... Button class code seems to indicate, that three `bcolor...` are indeed never initialized.

Comment: Which ones? Eclipse doesn't indicate anything.

Comment: It should, really. Check the constructor, you are not using it's parameters in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using paintComponent to draw the color of the button is not a good practice. It is an expensive operation.

I would suggest to use button.setBackgroundColor(yourColor). This way, you don't even have to bother drawing the button text using g2d.drawString().

FYI, you didn't use the constructor parameters at all. Below works for me:

```
public class Bouton extends JButton implements MouseListener{
public Bouton(String str, Color bcolornorm, Color bcolorhover, Color bcolorclic){
    super(str);
    this.name = str;
    this.bcolornorm = bcolornorm;
    this.bcolorhover = bcolorhover;
    this.bcolorclic = bcolorclic;
    this.setBackground(this.bcolornorm);
    this.addMouseListener(this);
}
private String name;
public Color bcolornorm;
public Color bcolorhover;
public Color bcolorclic;


public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
    this.setBackground(this.bcolorhover);
}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {
    this.setBackground(this.bcolornorm);
}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
    this.setBackground(this.bcolorclic);
}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
    this.setBackground(this.bcolorhover);
}
}
```

Comment: Oooh yeah I totally forgot to do this.bcolornorm = bcolornorm, etc. After doing this it works perfectly, thanks :D As for the paintComponent it was in the tutorial of openclassroom so I guess it is required for something.